# I just need the simplest way to put a letter above my bloxplot on R

Tags: r, plot

I don't use R on a daily basis, and I know that there are more improved ways to do this, but I have the code ready, I want to text over the bar without having to use ggplot or other mechanisms, how can I do it by " a "" b "" b "above the bars?

```
y1 = c(11.66, 8.03, 14, 11.5, 8.66)
y2 = c(3.86, 4.41, 2.66, 7,41, 7.8)
y3 = c(7.58, 5.83, 7.66, 5.16, 4.5)
boxplot(y1,y2,y3,names=c("Controle", "Maceração", "Infusão"),main="Germinação", ylim = c(0,15),
        xlab="Tratamento", ylab="IVG", col=(c("blue","red","green")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text` to add text over the bars.

```
y1 = c(11.66, 8.03, 14, 11.5, 8.66)
y2 = c(3.86, 4.41, 2.66, 7.41, 7.8)
y3 = c(7.58, 5.83, 7.66, 5.16, 4.5)
boxplot(y1,y2,y3,names=c("Controle", "Maceração", "Infusão"),
       main="Germinação", ylim = c(0,15),
        xlab="Tratamento", ylab="IVG", col=(c("blue","red","green")))
text( 
  x= 1:3, 
  y= c(max(y1), max(y2), max(y3)) + 0.8, 
  c('a', 'b', 'c') 
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much